# Do not activate OSGI declarative service depending on a java system property

Tags: java, osgi

Is it possible not to activate a OSGI declarative service depending on a java system property?

For example if i start java with the following property i do not want to start a certain DS:
-DdoNOtActivate=true

I thought about reading the propety in the activator of the specific DS but then what next? Call deactivate?

Edit:

Ok, I got the service itself working thanks to Balazs answer with programmatic activation, but my service also provided an interface for org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler and that part isn't working. I had this in my component.xml:

```
<service>
    <provide interface="org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler" />
    <provide interface="com.example.test.MyService" />
</service>

<property name="event.topics">
    test
</property>
```

So i removed the whole service part and left the event.topics part and in my java class activator i added the following:

```
myServiceReg = context.registerService(this.getClass().getName(), this, null);
eventHandlerReg = context.registerService(EventHandler.class.getName(), this, null);
```

So myService is activated and registered and everything works niceley. EventHandler also seems to be registered but no events reach my handleEvent() method.

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about reading the propety in the activator of the specific DS but then what next? Call deactivate?

Just return and do nothing. Do not use the automatic service registration but register and unregister the necessary OSGi service programmatically within the activate and deactivate method. E.g.:

```
private ServiceRegistration serviceReg;

@Activate
public void activate(BundleContext context) {
  String sysProp = System.getProperty("doNotActivate");
  if (sysProp != null && Boolean.parse(sysProp)) {
    return;
  }

  serviceReg = context.registerService(....);
}

@Deactivate
public void deactivate() {
  if (serviceReg != null) {
    serviceReg.unregister();
  }
}
```

You component will be active, but if the system property is specified, it will do nothing.

**Edit**

> So myService is activated and registered and everything works niceley. EventHandler also seems to be registered but no events reach my handleEvent() method.

Please note that you registered the service with no service properties. All properties of the component are added as service properties automatically, if the service registration is automatic. This is not the case if you register the service programmatically. I would change the code in the following way:

```
public void activate(ComponentContext cc) {    
  BundleContext bc = cc.getBundleContext();
  myServiceReg = bc.registerService(this.getClass().getName(), this, cc.getProperties());
  eventHandlerReg = bc.registerService(EventHandler.class.getName(), this, cc.getProperties());
}
```

By passing the properties of the component, the service will be registered with the same properties as it would be registered with the automatic method.

Comment: How can i not use automatic service registration? At the moment it seems my service is activated and registered automatically. Probably some kind of a property in component.xml?
Also what is this ServiceRegistration? Is it a reference i need to add to component.xml?

Comment: OSGi services can be installed programmatically with bundleContext.registerService() function. In that case, the programmer gets a ServiceRegistration instance, and the service can be unregistered with the unregister function of that instance. If the <service> element is not defined in component.xml, no service is registered automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Almost got it working but ran into another problem and I updated the question about it.